How to update many documents in MongoDB with new values
I have some documents like this:
{"title": "test1", sort: 1},
{"title": "test2", sort: 7},
{"title": "test3", sort: 5}

Now I want to reassign the sort field values with new values by the pattern like previous value plus 10
I want the result below:
{"title": "test1", sort: 1},
{"title": "test2", sort: 21},
{"title": "test3", sort: 11}

With many documents, what is the best way and with the best performance to perform this?


Use the $rank function of $setWindowFields to provide ranks 1, 2, 3, etc. which will be based on the existing sort value.

The final new-sort will be (rank - 1) x 10 + 1

Use the $out operation to write all the updated docs back to the same collection.


db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: { sort: 1 },
      output: {
        sort: { $rank: {} }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      sort: {
        $add: [
          1,
          {
            $multiply: [
              { $subtract: ["$sort", 1] },
              10
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "collection" }
])

Mongo Playground
Notes:

The lowest rank is 1 so that will be the first new-value of sort.
If your existing sort fields can have multiple docs with the same value, then some ranks will skip when there are ties. If you want them to always be sequential, use $denseRank instead of $rank.


Thanks @aneroid. Your code creates a new collection with new documents. But I want to update the existing collection documents, not to create a new one.

Then specify the same/source collection name in the $out stage. I've called it "collection" because that's the default name on Mongo Playground. If your collection is called "SortedTitles", then you should put the last stage as: { $out: "SortedTitles" }

For asking in easy way I wrote that sample data. But in real my documents have another parameter for example parent field. I want to group my documents with parent field and update and reassign new sort values in each group. Assume that each group starts the sort field value from 1.

Wrt "I want to group my documents with parent field" 1. Then specify that field for partitionBy in $setWindowFields. So the first stage will look like { $setWindowFields: { partitionBy: "$parent", sortBy: { sort: 1 }, output: { sort: { $rank: {} } } } }. 2. Read How to Ask, and the question checklist.

Wrt "For asking in easy way I wrote that sample data" - how does that help anyone? I've provided an answer to your question, then you change the criteria of your question and then I have to update it. The change needed in this case is minor, just one line. Otherwise, you've wasted my time and yours.

Sorry about that, and thank you for helping me. I rewrite my question again in https://stackoverflow.com/q/78341732/1773759
I'v be glad if you help me again
